# "Application windows are expected..." warning, but app runs fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, appdelegate, uiwindow

I'm getting the following error in my console upon launching my iPad-based iOS app:

`"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"`

I've looked at answers to other questions that reference this error, but none of them seem to be my particular issue.

In fact, the only symptom I have that there is a problem at all is the message in the console at app launch. My app seems to run fine and performs exactly as I desire.

I'm using a single storyboard file (Main.storyboard) to generate my app's UI (with a couple of XIB files for custom views). All of my `UIViewController` subclass UI is contained in the single storyboard. This storyboard is specified as the 'Main Interface' in my 'Deployment Info'.

Here is the code in my `AppDelegate` (I've removed some non-UI-based app initialization code):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    MSSAppSingleton *app                = [MSSAppSingleton singleton];

    // Other, non-UI code, like TestFlight, etc.

    UISplitViewController *split        = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *leftNavVc   = split.viewControllers[0];
    UINavigationController *rightNavVc  = split.viewControllers[1];
    app.containerSplitViewController    = split;

    app.leftRoot                        = leftNavVc.viewControllers[0];
    app.rightRoot                       = rightNavVc.viewControllers[0];

    return YES;
}
```

This code appears to run without a problem. I'm grabbing these references for later UI manipulation, and all of that is working as desired. Every single one of the lines of code above runs as I would expect. `self.window` has a valid reference. `self.window.rootViewController` does, too.

So, this isn't really a "problem", except I follow the philosophy of "treat every warning as an error" and would love to get this warning to disappear. Has anyone else seen this? I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and running the iPad 7.0.3 simulator.

Answer (score 1):

```
MSSAppSingleton *app                = [MSSAppSingleton singleton];
```

is supposed to be called before

```
app.containerSplitViewController    = split;
```

Comment: Sorry. I had removed that line and added it back in just to give context for the `app` variable. In the actual code, it's in the right spot. Good eye, but the code I posted wouldn't even compile! ;-) As I mentioned, the app runs fine without issue, except for the warning in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode likes it when you set the root view controller

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController: someViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I don't use storyboards myself though.

You may need to set the root instead of just getting it and then applying things to it to make it happy.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a completely mistaken answer when using storyboards. If you look at all of the Apple-supplied templates (when using storyboards), the entirety of the code in their application launch method is `return YES;`.